# Highchart type : X-Range no space between two data sets

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using X-Range I am trying to create a graph where two data sets are used. I am not able to remove space between two columns of x-range.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnEml.jpg)

[Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/5rmz28sL/2/)

HTML Code

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/xrange.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

JS code

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
    events: {
      render: function() {
        var chart = this,
          point = chart.series[0].points[0],
          imgSize = 22,
          x = point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + point.shapeArgs.width / 2 - imgSize / 2,
          y = point.plotY + chart.plotTop - point.shapeArgs.height - imgSize / 2,
          offsetTop = -5,
          svgElem;

        if (chart.customElemenst && chart.customElemenst.length) {
            chart.customElemenst.forEach(function(elem) {
            elem.destroy();
          });
        }

        chart.customElemenst = [];

        svgElem = chart.renderer.image(
          'images/Info_icon-72a7cf.svg.png', 
          x,
          y + offsetTop,
          imgSize,
          imgSize
        ).add();

        chart.customElemenst.push(svgElem);
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    categories: ['Machine Status'],
    reversed: true
  },
  legend:true,
  credits:false,
  /* plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderRadius: 0,

    }
  }, */
   plotOptions: {
    series: {
        borderRadius: 0,
      grouping: false,
      pointPadding: 0.7,
      dataLabels: {
        align: 'center',
        enabled: true,

       // format: "{point.name}"
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
     formatter: function () {
         return '<b>' + this.series.name + ' - ' + this.point.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %B %H:%M', this.point.x) +
             ' - ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e %H:%M', this.point.x2) + '<br/>';
     }
 },

  series: [{"name":"Active","strokewidth":10,"pointWidth":20,"color":"","data":[{"name":"Program Status","x":1564215451000,"x2":1564215511000,"y":0,"color":"#2cd345"},{"name":"Program Status","x":1564215511000,"x2":1564215571000,"y":0,"color":"#2cd345"},{"name":"Program Status","x":1564215571000,"x2":1564215631000,"y":0,"color":"#2cd345"},{"name":"Program Status","x":1564215751000,"x2":1564215811000,"y":0,"color":"#2cd345"},{"name":"Program Status","x":1564215871000,"x2":1564215931000,"y":0,"color":"#2cd345"},{"name":"Program Status","x":1564215931000,"x2":1564215991000,"y":0,"color":"#2cd345"}]},{"name":"Abort","pointWidth":20,"color":"","data":[{"name":"Program Status2","x":1564214400000,"x2":1564215269000,"y":0,"color":"#ff4040"},{"name":"Program Status2","x":1564215269000,"x2":1564215331000,"y":0,"color":"#ff4040"},{"name":"Program Status2","x":1564215331000,"x2":1564215391000,"y":0,"color":"#ff4040"},{"name":"Program Status2","x":1564215391000,"x2":1564215451000,"y":0,"color":"#ff4040"},{"name":"Program Status2","x":1564215631000,"x2":1564215691000,"y":0,"color":"#ff4040"},{"name":"Program Status2","x":1564215691000,"x2":1564215751000,"y":0,"color":"#ff4040"},{"name":"Program Status2","x":1564215811000,"x2":1564215871000,"y":0,"color":"#ff4040"}]}]
});
```

2nd issue which i have is below.

Also tried to combine two data sets in a single series but in that case not able to have legends on series ->data -> name.
below is the jsfiddle for that. the legends should be Active,Abort

[Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ajitrishabh/ynp1s96h/8/)

Comment: Fixed through css https://jsfiddle.net/xz68buhk/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove spaces you can set `series.borderWidth = 1` and the same color for the border as the particular series color.

**Code:**

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderRadius: 0,
      borderWidth: 1,
      grouping: false,
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    "name": "Active",
    "strokeWidth": 0,
    "pointWidth": 20,
    borderColor: '#2cd345',
    ...
  }]
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tqpLmvs5/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.xrange.borderColor
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.xrange.borderWidth

---

**EDIT**

The second issue can be resolved by adding this piece of code:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
    events: {
      render: function() {
        var chart = this;

        chart.legend.allItems.forEach(function(item) {
          item.legendSymbol.attr({
            fill: item.options.borderColor
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7vrtw4o9/

Comment: thanks. how about the 2nd problem where i need legends based on series ->data->name ?

Comment: for the solution provided legends are not as per series color

Comment: i was taking about this legends for this https://jsfiddle.net/ajitrishabh/ynp1s96h/8/ issue

Comment: A better idea is to separate data into two series as in the attached example.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this through css. https://jsfiddle.net/xz68buhk/

```
.highcharts-series-0 rect {
  stroke: rgb(44,211,69);
  opacity: 1
 }

.highcharts-series-1 rect {
  stroke: rgb(255, 89, 89);
  opacity: 1
 }

 .highcharts-series-0 .highcharts-point  {
   stroke: rgb(44,211,69);    
 }

 .highcharts-series-1 .highcharts-point  {
   stroke: #ff4040;    
 }
```